# Why couldn't i mount windows 7 partition when it is hibernated?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, mount, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

When i try to mount windows 7 partition when it is hibernated the system give me this message :

[image: Hibernated partition message]

so Why this happen, and can i mount it read/write ?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernation is basically a snapshot of a running OS, with all its running applications, open files (maybe in the middle of a write operation), file caches etc.

If you mount a hibernated partition from another OS and change data on disk - the actual state of the disk and what Windows knows of the disk goes out of sync, which can lead to severe corruption of the filesystem.

The accepted answer at [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) provides more details.